# Loading script outside of html document

Tags: javascript, html

I came accross this html snippet & to my surprise jQuery Object does get created!

```
<!doctype html>
<body>
<h1>Hello World</h1>
</body>
</html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.js"></script>
```

As you may notice `<script>` tag comes *AFTER* closing `</html>` tag. I wonder how & why does this even work?

Comment: Browsers are very error tolerant. They have to be, you'd be lucky to find a single strictly standards compliant page on the Internet.

Comment: try your code on ie6 or 7 and see the result :p

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It works because browsers are very forgiving, there is no benefit to doing it this way.

The reason it is there, is probably because someone misunderstood what was meant by 'putting scripts as far down the page as possible'…

Comment: What is impact on DomContentLoaded event when JS is placed outside HTML. Whether DomContentLoaded event is fired before this javascript is executed?

Answer (score 3):

If you validate the file, it would say it is not valid. However, browsers will usualy try and do things the way you probably meant them.

Browsers just aren't that strict. You can do alot of things wrong and they would still work.

Answer (score 1):

I checked this code for firefox , script is treated as inside body tag for this particular case .

Browsers are really Error tolerant indeed .