# Javascript not getting executed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Designing a login page for portal written in php and using mysql. Somehow my javascript after entering correct detail is not getting executed. Below is the code:

```
<?php
include_once dirname(dirname(__FILE__))."/const.php";
include_once PHP_PATH.'/config.php';

        //Logic to validate login details 
        if(isset($_POST ['Login']))
            {
                //Start your session
            if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
            }

                // Connect to database

                $username ='';
                $password ='';

                    if (isset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']) && (time() - $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] > 1800)) {
                    // last request was more than 30 minutes ago
                      session_unset();     // unset $_SESSION variable for the run-time 
                      session_destroy();   // destroy session data in storage  header("location:logout.php"); }

                    if (!isset($_SESSION['CREATED'])) {
                      $_SESSION['CREATED'] = time();
                    } else if (time() - $_SESSION['CREATED'] > 1800) {
                    // session started more than 30 minutes ago
                      session_regenerate_id(true);    // change session ID for the current session and invalidate old session ID
                      $_SESSION['CREATED'] = time();  // update creation time
                    }
                // Assign local variables to posted data
                    $username = trim($_POST['uname']);
                    $password = trim($_POST['password']);

                  $username = stripslashes($username);
                  $password = stripcslashes($password);
                  $md5_password = md5($password);

                $query = "SELECT f_name, active,pk_user_id FROM tbl_users  WHERE email ='$username' and password ='$md5_password'";                               
                $data=mysqli_query($conn,$query)or die(mysqli_error($conn));   

                mysqli_close($conn);
              if(!empty($row=mysqli_fetch_array($data))){
                  if ($row[1]!=0){
                  $seconds = 60*30 + time();
                  setcookie(loggedin, date("F js - g:i a"), $seconds);

                  $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time(); // update last activity time stamp 

                  //Store the name in the session
                   $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                   $_SESSION['name'] = $row[0];
                   $_SESSION['pk_user_id'] = $row[2];

                    //echo $row[0];
                    //echo 'Login successful';
                    header("location:login_success.php");
                  }else{
                                          ?>
                      <script type="text/javascript"> 
                       history.back(); 
                        alert("Please verify your account before login");                             
                      </script> 
                    <?php
                  }

              }  elseif(empty ($username)or empty ($password)){
                    ?>
                       <script type="text/javascript"> 
                       history.back(); 
                        alert("Please enter Username and Password");                             
                      </script> 
                    <?php
                   }
                    else{

                        ?> 
                            <script type="text/javascript"> 
                            history.back(); 
                            alert("Incorrect Login Details"); 

                            </script> 
                        <?php

                   }       
            }
        }

        ?>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>login</title>
        <!-- CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,300,500">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=ASSET_PATH?>bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=ASSET_PATH?>font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=ASSET_PATH?>css/form-elements.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=ASSET_PATH?>css/style.css">
        <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

        <!-- Favicon and touch icons -->
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?=ASSET_PATH?>ico/favicon.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="<?=ASSET_PATH?>ico/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="<?=ASSET_PATH?>ico/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="<?=ASSET_PATH?>ico/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="<?=ASSET_PATH?>ico/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png">

    </head>

    <body>
      <form name="Home" action="index.php" class="login-form" method ="POST">
        <!-- Top content -->
        <div class="top-content">

            <div class="inner-bg">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 text">
                            <h1><strong>Gurukul</strong>&nbsp;Student Portal</h1>
                            <div><big><label style="font-family: Comic Sans MS;">New User?</label><span style="font-family: Comic Sans MS;"> </span><a style="font-family: Comic Sans MS; color: red;" href="register_form.php" target="_blank">Click here</a></big>&nbsp;to Register
                            <div class="description">
                                <p>
                                    Please enter your credentials below:
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 form-box">
                            <div class="form-top">
                                <div class="form-top-left">
                                    <h3>Login to our site</h3>
                                    <p>Enter your username and password to log on:</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-top-right">
                                    <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-bottom">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="sr-only" for="uname">Username</label>
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                                        <input type="text" name="uname" placeholder="Username..." class="form-username form-control" id="uname">
                                        </div>
                                        <a href="forgot_username.php">Forgot Username ?</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="sr-only" for="form-password">Password</label>
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
                                        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password..." class="form-password form-control" id="password">
                                        </div>
                                        <a href="forgot_pwd_form.php">Forgot password ?</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <button name="Login" type="submit" class="btn">Sign in!</button>
                                    <button name="Cancel" type="reset" class="btn">Cancel</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

          </div>
        </form>


        <!-- Javascript -->
        <script src="<?=ASSET_PATH?>js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="<?=ASSET_PATH?>bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="<?=ASSET_PATH?>js/jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>
        <script src="<?=ASSET_PATH?>js/scripts.js"></script>

        <!--[if lt IE 10]>
            <script src="<?=ASSET_PATH?>js/placeholder.js"></script>

        <![endif]-->

    </body>
</html
```

The config files contain db details which are correct and constant file include path are also getting executed properly. After entering the correct details the page just refresh and it stays on same page itself. I tried checking console but its not showing any response. Not sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: Your query is not safe from injection attacks.  Please implement mysqli prepared statements with placeholders for security reasons.

Comment: Just check `if($row=mysqli_fetch_array($data)){`  you don't need `empty()`.  You also use `if ($row[1]){`.  You don't expect your alerts to work do you?

Comment: md5 hashes for passwords are no longer considered to be adequate.  Please read php's page for password hashing.  http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php

Comment: How about `.go(-1)` ?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25673477/window-history-back-not-working

Answer (score 2):

Your Javascript is — not — inside of `<HTML></HTML>`.

That is why it is — not — executed.

Comment: Writing script tags before html tags will work (afaik), but it will be invalid markup.

Comment: I wonder. Here it says after `HTML` will work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6895865/loading-script-outside-of-html-document. Perhaps before — not. And depending on browser the OP uses I guess. @mickmackusa

Comment: I only found a comment that supports my claim... so not the best backing.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22794684/script-tag-position-before-html-tag

Comment: There is no `<!DOCTYPE>` in the question. Perhaps that’s why. @mickmackusa

Comment: That's a sensible insight.  @Jigna can you try with a doctype declaration.